# cakephp save related model without foreign key

Tags: cakephp

I would like to create a new model using another parameter

```
class Beacon extends AppModel {

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'name';

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'UUID' => array(
            'uuid' => array(
                'rule' => array('uuid'),

            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * hasOne associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasOne = array(
        'Position' => array(
            'className' => 'Position',
            'foreignKey' => 'beacon_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

I would like to ping this beacon passing in parameter the beacon UUID not the primary key.

```
class Ping extends AppModel {

//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Beacon' => array(
            'className' => 'Beacon',
            'foreignKey' => 'beacon_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

How do I create a Ping object without the beacon primary_key but the UUID ?

on the ping controller I would like to add

```
public function pingBeaconWithUUID($uuid) {
```

How do I manage that ?
Thanks !

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Did you get an error? Wouldn't you just write code that uses the $uuid parameter to lookup the Beacon's id, then uses that value in the beacon_id field?

Comment: My question is pretty basic sorry : The thing is I don't know what to write after public function pingBeaconWithUUID($uuid) {
$this->Ping->create();
$this->Ping->save(?????)

Comment: oh myyy.... did you ever do the blog tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

If the UUID is unique you can use it as value for the id field. The id needs not to be an integer although it is preferable.

But I would also propose to use the approach by AgRizzo and look up the id.